# How to make image on ionic navbar still visible while it overflow

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a design from Photoshop. I want to implement that to my ionic project, but I don't know how. It's hard to implement the css style to make logo still visible when it overflow the navbar container.

My project looks like this:

[image: My Design]

My Photoshop design:

[image: My Project Look]

---

And my CSS code

```
.brand-image {
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 40%; }
```

and the HTML

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <img src="/assets/imgs/brand-image.svg" class="brand-image">
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: use `position:absolute;bottom:-20px;` it will help you by the way you have to put some code here so we can help or jsfiddle

Comment: its not working, i already do that, ill attach my css code above.

Answer (score 2):

Add the below css to your **app.scss**

```
ion-navbar.toolbar {
    overflow: visible;
    contain: none;
}
```

Comment: is `contain: none;` is the problem?

Comment: No, by default ionic has set `overflow: hidden` and `contain: content` to the navbar to prevent overflowing stuff inside it from overlapping the content below. Have you tried the solution?